If a pocket of nitrogen gas is pumped in at the bottom intake of a padded tank will the pocket of gas bubble up?
I have a nitrogen gas padded tank (tank 1) which is filled from the bottom of the tank. Tank has a set point of 30 psi which adjusted as tank level changes. Also at the inlet is an additional pipe attached to a 10 gallon recovery tank. The recovery tank is also padded to its nitrogen gas. When the recovery tank is full, the liquid is pumped back into tank 1. The pump is a Venturi pump. When this occurs a pocket of gas is also entering tank 1. My question is would that pocket of gas remain trapped below the fluid or bubble up to the top of the liquid? The Venturi pump is set to 40 psi and with the tank 1 maintaining 30 psi, would the pocket of gas bubble by lowering tank 1 set point from 30 psi to a lower value?
Currently when the recovery tank pumps back into the tank, a small pocket of nitrogen is discharged at the tank outlet.
Update: I realize that the way I posted the question it comes across as if I am asking for a direct “fix” for this issue. I want to clarify that yes a pocket of gas is getting trapped from the recovery tank. I can reprogram the automated process so stopping the gas from entering the tank. However, I should’ve worded the question asking help with an explanation as to why the gas stays trapped. Is it due to the tank blanket pressure, wine viscosity, combination of the two, or some other condition(s)? I would like to understand what is occurring here.

Either the question is very trivial, what I hesitate to believe, either the true question is well veiled by the used formulation, adding additional layer to the problem to be solved. // What is the geometry of the vessel and phase distribution? If the gas has upward path wider than  very few mm, and if gaseous phase forms region bigger than very few mm, than it would bubble upwards.

Poutnik, appreciate the reply.  I can assure you that I am not trying to veil anything. I am an automation engineer tasked to help a customer solve this issue. As an automation engineer I am a programmer. This is typically sorted out by the process engineer, but they couldn’t. I will say that I have to be careful with some information as this layout/design is proprietary. I was trying to be careful which is why I initially omitted that the fluid is wine and why the diagram is cropped with wording scratched out. However the issue is as I described.

As the diagram is intended more to technology engineers, it may be good to add some non-engineer drawing of simple, geometrical schema, focused just on the system details of interest. I assume there are 2 vessels connected by tubing, with some size, shape, volume and pressure parameters. add some legend to such a schema and readers would get the idea of the scenario much easier.

I will be going to take a look at the layout this week. This will allow me to note down the correct details. I do know the following information. Based on drawing, the top tank (tank 1) is 150 gallons (568 liters) the recovery tank is 5 gallons (19 liters) the green line is a pipe with an inner diameter of 3/4 inches (19 mm) The nitrogen gas is fed from the top of the recovery tank (green line) at a constant 50 psi. Tank 1 is padded with nitrogen gas set for 30 psi. Thank you
